# Шаблон для терма таксономии

Tags: wordpress

Имеется таксономия `custom`, к примеру, и в ней есть терм `special`. И я хочу, чтобы этот терм подцеплял свой кастомный шаблон. Для стандартных таксономий выводится `taxonomy-custom.php`, а для этой, по идее, должен работать `taxonomy-custom-special.php`, но он почему-то не цепляется.

Comment: После того, как вы прописали шаблон, вам необходимо зайти в Админку, Настройки->Постоянные ссылки и нажать "Сохранить изменения" (либо изменить на какой-то другой вариант, а потом вернуть как было). Плюс если есть кэш, его нужно сбросить.  После этого изменения должны примениться. Но это при условии, что вы не допустили других ошибок.

Comment: @rusgeli в последних версиях WP никаких манипуляций на станице постоянных ссылок в админке делать не надо, даже на кнопку нажимать. Просто туда зайти. При зарузке этой страницы ядро вызывает `flush_rewrite_rules()`.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, только неделю назад столкнулся с тем, что мне пришлось это сделать, чтобы шаблон архива заработал. Wordpress 6.1.1

Comment: Если постоянные ссылки не сбрасывались - у вас была другая проблема. Смотрим код ядра: https://i.imgur.com/OHfgEw1.png Видим, что flush_reqrite_rules вызывается до вывода админ-заголовка на странце постоянных ссылок.

Comment: @KAGGDesign вообще-то "просто зайти" было достаточно ещё в 3.какой-то :) Просто это как правило не уточнялось, тк выглядит сие действо несколько странно и непонятно :). Ну и не все советующие знают этот финт.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за ответы! На самом деле все гораздо проще оказалось - в файле functions.php был жестко задан шаблон для данной таксономии)